# Create report including data from contact and from related contact

Tags: relationships, reports, custom-reports

I have contacts who are parents and related to contacts who are children. Child is registered for an event. Parent is not registered for any event.

I want to create a report that lists each child and includes:

- Child's Contact ID,
- Child's name,
- Child's birthdate,
- Child's Event's name,
- Child's Event status (for example 'Registered'),
- Child's custom field data (for several custom fields),
- Parent's Contact ID,
- Parent's name,
- Parent's emails,
- Parent's phone numbers,

I can create reports for all of the Parent's data.
I can create reports for a Child's data (events and custom data).

I cannot figure out how to create a report in civi that includes both. How is that possible? What am I missing?

I am using CiviCRM 5.45.6  on Drupal 8

Answer (score 2):

In latest versions of CiviCRM searchkit should do this.

Participant search> Event Name and Status

Link contact details from Participant record> Child Data

Parent Details> Bring in related contacts from child record

This demo from a meetup is as good an intro to Searchkit as I've found
https://civicrm.org/blog/wmortada/searchkit-new-way-get-data-out-civicrm

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best option for this would be to use the data processor extension, which allows you to present related information on the same screen. You can then add options to PDF/CSV export if it needs downloading.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor